# How to create a RESTful object with server calculated fields

Tags: http, rest, http-verbs, idempotent

I have an object:

```
Account
{
    Id,
    Name,
    CurrentBalance
}
```

`Id` is an immutable key, `Name` is a mutable string, and `CurrentBalance` is calculated from all of the transactions associated with the account.

I am stuck on the fact that `GET \Accounts\{Id}` will not be idempotent because changes to a transaction will cause a change in `CurrentBalance`. Should I remove this field from the object and make a request like

```
POST \Accounts\{Id}\CurrentBalance
```

But now I have to make multiple calls to the server to get the `CurrentBalance` of all objects:

```
GET \Accounts
POST \Accounts\{Id1}\CurrentBalance
POST \Accounts\{Id2}\CurrentBalance
POST \Accounts\{Id3}\CurrentBalance
....
```

I guess I am just looking to see if there is already a standard way to handle this that I am missing?

**UPDATE**

Part 2 if the original object is ok via GET. My only way to update the `Account.Name` is via a PATCH as I cannot allow an update to CurrentBalance, correct?

**NOTE**

I realize I could put this on the client to have to get all transactions and calculate it, but I would prefer to do this on the server for multiple reasons

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Idempotency does not mean that you must always get the same response back.

Consider the resource `/TodaysWeather`.  It would be pretty useless if it always returned the same value.

Idempotency simply states that if a client makes the same request multiple times instead of just once, the impact on the system (from the client's perspective) will be the same.

Comment: Thanks, I see your point and it makes sense. I am going to add a bounty when eligible to get more eyes on this. Hopefully that will just mean validation for what you are saying :)

Comment: Also, I just updated my question as I ran into what originally got me to this train of thought...updating the account...I cannot use a PUT and must go with a PATCH or POST (if I leave it as is)?

Comment: @JustinPihony As long as you include all of the properties that _can_ be updated in your PUT then it is still considered a complete replacement.

Answer (score 1):

I just re-read the [HTTP specs](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html) and realized that if I want to be truly `RESTful` I have to make multiple calls because GET has to be safe.

> In particular, the convention has been established that the GET and
>   HEAD methods SHOULD NOT have the significance of taking an action
>   other than retrieval.

I am not deleting this question because I think it could help others in the future, but if the majority disagree I will delete it

Answer (score 1):

If it's important that you're able to PUT some data, then immediately retrieve the same data via GET, then you could simply treat it as a different resource entirely, e.g.:

```
# Change an account name
PUT \Accounts\{id}

# Get accounts/names/balances
GET \AccountDetails

# Get balance of an account
GET \AccountDetails\{id}\CurrentBalance
```

However, **there's really no good reason to go through the trouble of doing that**. Your PUT is idempotent as long as making the same request multiple times doesn't change the state of the system. **Not** changing the system's state if some spurious value is submitted is the correct behavior. In fact, if someone does try a PUT including CurrentBalance, you might want to return a 400 (Bad Request) status explaining that CurrentBalance can't be updated.